# How to combine find and update to 1 update

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using Spring Data MongoTemplate, trying to optimize mongodb update. Can I make **only 1 update** without a `find()` to check `status` of the document in db first:

- If status is not "Blocked", update the status and add to the
  actions.
- If status is "Blocked", just add to the actions, not update to the status.

```
Java object to update:
status: "Display",
action: "Show"

mongodb:
{
    status: "Blocked",
    actions: [
        "Show",
        "Hide",
        "Show",
        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: @ray I want the actions property is always be updated to keep track.
Thank you, now I know Mongo playground!

Comment: Just 1 more little thing that new action is in the first position in array.

Comment: Try [this updated Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e_OUlbr-bou)

Comment: This is what I want, thank so much for your quick reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an update with aggregation pipeline. Do the conditional checking on the status field in the `$addFields` stage.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "userInput": {
        status: "Display",
        action: "Show"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "status": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $ne: [
              "$status",
              "Blocked"
            ]
          },
          "then": "$userInput.status",
          "else": "Blocked"
        }
      },
      actions: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          [
            "$userInput.action"
          ],
          "$actions"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "userInput"
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e_OUlbr-bou) for your reference.